# Binary matrix with columns sums equal to an array numbers, with unique rows sums

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I have this input array:

```
[5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4]
```

and want to build binary matrices where sums of each column equal to the coresponding input array elements.

The matrix is of size `7 x 5`.
The sums of rows create an array of numbers (of size 5 in this case). So I need to generate different combinations of columns so that the arrays of rows sums are uninque.

The initial matrix is this:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

And the rows sums arrays will be

```
[7, 6, 5, 3, 1]
```

I understand that I could create all possible permutations for each column and then take only the unique rows sums arrays (like `[7, 6, 4, 3, 2], [6, 6, 5, 3, 2]`).

But could someone give an advice on how could it be optimized, or if there's an algorithm for this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to find all possible (distinct) arrays of row sums given an array of column sums?

Comment: Well I'd like to have the corresponding matrices too (to know which columns are 0's an 1's). But at least row sums arrays would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Perform permutations only on unique column sum values.
In the case of `[5,3,2,4,1,3,4]`, you would want to perform permutations on the columns which are in **bold**: [**5**,**3**,**2**,**4**,**1**,3,4], and keep the last 2 columns fixed in all your permutations.

Next, take the set of complementary columns: The columns where your column sum values add up to the total number of rows. In this case, column sum values `[3,2]` and `[4,1]` are complementary. While performing permutations for those columns, you would want to avoid multiple occurrences of rows sum matrix having all values 1.

For example if all permutations of `[3,2]` are performed, there would be `5C2` occurrence of row sum matrix = `[1,1,1,1,1]` corresponding to only those 2 columns.

So, if you avoid that particular duplicate, I guess this method should work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll definitely give it a try.